# Spring boot web services metrics monitoring

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, metrics

I have a spring-boot project that communicates with another legacy service via SOAP.

To do that I am using spring-boot-starter-web-services (2.0.8.RELEASE). I need to add metrics for SOAP response from legacy service (number of requests with status code 200, non-200, etc.)

My project has a dependency on spring-boot-actuator, but unfortunately, I found nothing in actuator/micrometer documentation how to do that.

Is it possible to enable metrics for WebServiceTemplate that is actually used for sending/receiving data from remote services (something similar that actuator does for RestTemplate/WebClient) or I need to add some custom code for this?

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, I think what you are asking about is HTTP tracing, which is already there in the actuator. Or you can write a custom one because as I remember, HTTP tracing shows only the last 100 HTTP request/response. You can consider creating your own `HttpExchangeTracer` implementaion to achieve this.

Comment: I need something similar to actuator/metrics/http.client.requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution:
There is `org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.EndpointInterceptorAdapter` that intercepts requests/responses, so by extending EndpointInterceptorAdapter (or implementing EndpointInterceptor) additional logic can be added.
I created counter:

```
Counter.Builder responseStatusCounter = Counter
        .builder("soap.server.response")
        .baseUnit("responses");
```

and in `EndpointInterceptorAdapter#afterCompletion` analyse SOAP response and count either error or success responses:

```
@Override
public void afterCompletion(final MessageContext messageContext,
                            final Object endpoint, final Exception ex) throws Exception {
    WebServiceMessage message = messageContext.getResponse();
    SaajSoapMessage saajSoapMessage = (SaajSoapMessage) message;
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = saajSoapMessage.getSaajMessage();

    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope soapEnvelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody soapBody = soapEnvelope.getBody();
    SOAPFault soapFault = soapBody.getFault();

    responseStatusCounter
        .description(getDescription(soapFault))
        .tags("code", soapFault != null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(soapFault.getFaultString()) ? "error" : "ok")
        .register(meterRegistry)
        .increment();
}
```

For web client, that sends SOAP requests in application, I use `javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler`:

```
public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context) {
    log.info("Computing response status count");
    SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
    SOAPBody body = message.getSOAPBody();
    SOAPFault fault = body.getFault();
    responseStatusCounter
        .tags("code", fault != null ? "error" : "ok")
        .register(meterRegistry)
        .increment();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how can we get the time (duration) of a SOAP request?

Comment: What is getDescription and meterRegistry?

Comment: @PauloPedroso in method getDescription I just extract some xml field that holds some error text. meterRegistry is a bean of https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.3.3/io/micrometer/core/instrument/MeterRegistry.html. I pass it to constructor during interseptor creation